# How to combine JPEG / webp / jpg2000 / JPEG XR with responsive images using srcset and sizes?

Tags: css, image, responsive-images, srcset

I'm getting really confused about how to best implement different next-gen (JPEG / webp / jpg2000 / JPEG XR) image formats with responsive srcset images?

I would like to have different sizes of images for different screen widths, but also different resolution from different next-gen image format. And a fallback. How to write this down, when I have let's say:

1 image in 4 sizes and with jpeg, webp, jpg2000, jpg xr format and have 3 different breakpoints.

I thought I can use < picture > element and in that one I will use < srcset >, but I just read on one site:
"The < picture > element’s child < img > element is required, and that child should not have its own srcset and sizes attributes because that functionality will be shifted to the < source > element."

Comment: Fwiw, JPEG 2000 is only supported by Safari; and JPEG XR is only supported by IE and old (non-Chromium) Edge, and in the latter, negatively [impacts](https://calendar.perfplanet.com/2018/dont-use-jpeg-xr-on-the-web/) performance.

Answer (score 1):

`IMG` element inside [`PICTURE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) is needed as a fallback for browsers that don’t support `PICTURE`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer on how to use the srcset+sizes inside of  tag:

```
<picture class="my-first-class">
                <source
                type="image/webp"
                    sizes="(min-width: 701px) 22vw,
                            (min-width: 1000px) 19vw,
                            35vw"
                    srcset="
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_190.webp 190w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_321.webp 321w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_420.webp 420w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_507.webp 507w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_584.webp 584w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_653.webp 653w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_718.webp 718w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_781.webp 781w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_842.webp 842w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_900.webp 900w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_955.webp 955w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_1006.webp 1006w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_1060.webp 1060w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_1111.webp 1111w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_1160.webp 1160w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_1210.webp 1210w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_1260.webp 1260w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_1309.webp 1309w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_1353.webp 1353w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_1380.webp 1380w">                      
                <source
                    type="image/jpeg"
                    sizes="(min-width: 701px) 22vw,
                            (min-width: 1000px) 19vw,
                            35vw"
                    srcset="
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_190.jpg 190w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_321.jpg 321w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_420.jpg 420w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_507.jpg 507w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_584.jpg 584w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_653.jpg 653w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_718.jpg 718w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_781.jpg 781w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_842.jpg 842w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_900.jpg 900w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_955.jpg 955w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_1006.jpg 1006w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_1060.jpg 1060w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_1111.jpg 1111w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_1160.jpg 1160w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_1210.jpg 1210w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_1260.jpg 1260w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_1309.jpg 1309w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_1353.jpg 1353w,
                            img/hilti-png/hilti-png_1380.jpg 1380w">
                <img src="img/hilti-png/hilti-png_781.jpg"
                    alt="hilti"
                    class="my class">                        
            </picture>
```

Comment: My code is now ugly, but performance rose from 68 to 94 on a gallery page. Thank you!